# Autofac - Use the same DbContext across multiple repositories

Tags: autofac

I have a desktop app using Autofac. The framework I'm using doesn't provide hooks for dependency injection and thus the view models are instantiated using the service locator pattern.

One of my view models has two repositories that it uses. The repositories both take a single object, with is the applications `DbContext`.

Autofac instantiates two `DbContext` instances - one for each repository. The two repositories should use the same `DbContext` instance.

The service locator is implemented as:

```
            ServiceLocator.Current = new ServiceLocator((type) =>
            {
                var resolved = _container.Resolve(type);
                return resolved;
            });
```

Where `_container` is an `IContainer` instance built thusly:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
/* snip */
_container = builder.Build();
```

How can I have Autofac use the same `DbContext` for all dependencies when creating the instance of the view model?

I definitely *don't* want a singleton context - subsequent instantiations of the view model, or other view models, should yield a different `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ custom lifetime scopes for that (https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html).
The idea is to register `DbContext` with `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` and then create a lifetime scope for every instance of view model. Autofac would create a single instance of `DbContext` per lifetime scope (and, thus, per view model).

The issue would be that custom lifetime scopes require manual disposal so you'd need to take care of `LifetimeScope.Dipose()` call after your view model is no longer needed.